# Suppose that $\lim_{x \to c}f(x) = L $ where $L > 0$ and $\lim_{x \to c}g(x) = \infty$. Show that $\lim_{x \to c}f(x)g(x)= \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Suppose that $\lim_{x \to c}f(x) = L $ where $L > 0$ and $\lim_{x \to
> > c}g(x) = \infty$. Show that $\lim_{x \to c}f(x)g(x)= \infty$. If L=0
>   show by example that this conclusion may fail

I don't know if there is anything to prove in this

$\lim_{x \to c}f(x)g(x) = \lim_{x \to c}f(x) \times \lim_{x \to c }g(x)= L \times \infty = \infty$ since $L>0$

Is this much proof okay ?

Also for the second part if we take $c=0$

$f(x)=x \to L = 0 \; as \; x \to 0$

$g(x) = \frac{1}{x^2} \to \infty \; as \; x \to 0$

$f(x)g(x) = \frac{1}{x} $ which does not tends to $\infty$ as $x \to 0$

Comment: The meaning of $\lim_{x \to c} g(x) = \infty$ is that $g(x)$ does not converge to any finite positive number, since it eventually crosses all of them. This does not allow us to use the multiplication theorem. Furthermore, if $lim_{x \to c} f(x) = 0$, then what does $0 \times \infty$ mean or equal?

Answer (score 1):

You mainly have the right intuition, you just need to write it down better:
Since $f(x)\rightarrow L>0$, you can find a $\delta>0$ such that for every $x\in (c-\delta,c+\delta)$ you have $f(x)\geq\varepsilon>0$. Hence for these $x$
$$\varepsilon g(x)\leq f(x)g(x)$$
Please finish the rest of the proof yourselve by checking the definition of $$\lim_{x\rightarrow c}g(x)=\infty :\Leftrightarrow \forall M\in\mathbb{R}\ \exists \delta >0 \ \forall x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta):\ g(x)\geq M$$
for $f(x)g(x)$.

For the second part: $\frac{1}{x}$ does not converge, if $x\rightarrow 0$. On the contrary, you have
$$\lim_{x\searrow 0}\frac{1}{x}=\infty.$$
Maybe you should choose $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ instead.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what is meant by that tilted downwards arrow in limit that you've used... also I need g(x) to be tending to infinity as x tends to 0... so how will $1/x$ satisfy that criterion. an is my example invalid ?

Comment: I think we need to make use of that fact that since $L > 0$ $ \exists V_{\delta}(c) $ such that $f(x) > 0$
Now using this $f(x)g(x)> \alpha \forall \alpha > 0$ and hence $ \to \infty$

can you still clarify the example part please

Comment: $x \searrow 0$ means the upper limit, i.e. you only choose $x>0$ for you approximation. In this strict sense your example works, since the lower limit (i.e. approximating with $x<0$) would be $-\infty$. What I suggested, was that the limit of $f(x)g(x)$ can even be bounded away from $\pm \infty$.